# Allure is not generating report on cucumber 7

Tags: selenium, junit, automation, cucumber, allure

After updating the cucumber version to 7.2.3, Allure not generating reports. (unknown report and NaN%). It still uses the config file in the directory. I think it's not about the folder path. If I decrease the version to 5.6.0 it is working.

The related part of the pom.xml is like below.

Does anyone have a solution for this??

Thanks,

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-cucumber7-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.3</version>
        </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

```
 <argLine>
    -Dcucumber.options="--plugin io.qameta.allure.cucumber7jvm.AllureCucumber7Jvm                
 </argLine>
```

Comment: I have the same issue. The problem is that nothing is being generated in `build/allure-results` (gradle). With Cucumber 6 everything worked fine.
What i noticed is that Allure doesnt have `cucumber7Jvm` in Adapter configuration when configuring it in `allure` task in gradle

Answer (score 1):

I know that it doesn't answer the exact question but hope it can help somebody.

I had the same issue with Gradle - `build/allure-results` folder had only one small `json` file that generated empty allure report.
It seems like not all the Cucumber and Allure versions are compatible with each other. So I have found a compatible versions pair of Cucumber and Allure. Surprisingly they are the same as author has:

```
cucumberVersion = '7.2.3'
allureVersion = '2.17.3'
```

related part of my `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'io.qameta.allure' version '2.9.1'
}

apply plugin: 'io.qameta.allure'

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '7.2.3'
    testImplementation group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '7.2.3'
    implementation group: 'io.qameta.allure', name: 'allure-cucumber7-jvm', version: '2.17.3'
}

configurations {
    cucumberRuntime {
        extendsFrom testImplementation
    }
}

task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, testClasses
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "io.cucumber.core.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['--plugin', 'html:results.html',
                    '--plugin', 'pretty',
                    '--plugin', 'io.qameta.allure.cucumber7jvm.AllureCucumber7Jvm',
                    '--glue', 'step_definitions',
                    'src/test/resources']
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, no this problem is not depend any cucumber version. Allure report have to write allure-result to any folder on test executing so you can use this commandline under `<argLine>` raw your pom.xml.

```
  <systemPropertyVariables>
   <allure.results.directory>
     ${project.build.directory}/allure-results
   </allure.results.directory>
 </systemPropertyVariables>
```